# FILTER leaving behind ghost values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some FILTER functions lined up in the grey cells shown below.

The problem is that when data changes, oftentimes Sheets will leave behind ghost values that need to be manually deleted. There's no way I can keep doing that. It's totally breaking the functionality of my spreadsheet.

The only valid FILTER result is in Column M shown below. You can tell because there's actually a value in the grey cell.

[Data With Ghost Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0prVH.png)

How can I get around this glitch? Is there a way to force these formulas to refresh or something? I tried   SpreadsheetApp.flush(); and that didn't do anything.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet? It sounds like something strange is going on because formula can't leave behind values if they are deleted. You mention `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` so maybe you have some Apps Script going on behind the scenes, are you able to share that?

Comment: This is a known bug and only happens when you have two filters immediately next to one another.

Comment: @MattKing do you have a link to the issue?

Comment: I'm working on the escalation at the Google Product Forums. Will post back here when I complete it

Comment: @iansedano The issue isn't that the formulas are leaving behind values when they are deleted. The issue is that the actual results for the FILTER change, but the changes are not being reflected in the actual output onscreen. So, say for example, it was filtering 10 results at one point. Then, the criteria changed and now there are zero results. What happens then is that the old results just "stick" there and have to be manually deleted. The only value that actually disappears like it should is the one with the formula itself -- all the other results below remain.

Comment: @iansedano Here's my video i included in my escalation to the Google Engineers.
https://www.loom.com/share/bb8b835d7fdf4f6391dc4c27336680dc

Comment: @MattKing thats very clear thanks, is there not a corresponding issue tracker link for this tough?

Comment: This is amazing; thanks for all the help! I never thought this would actually get answered so thoroughly, let alone get escalated to Google Engineers! @MattKing if you have a moment, could you look at my question below about the one more version of the formula needed? Search the term "Row 818" and it will show below; thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime You should never need to have multiple FILTER() formulas next to one another that are filtering based on the same thing.

write just ONE filter formula with your desired ranges placed in curly brackets with commas between like this:

```
=FILTER({Data!A2:A,Data!G2:G,Data!X2:X}, Data!B2:B>= A230)
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure if that would work for my situation..?

[Here is a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ki5SwWfjHiRegew7-M8Ryv5gKyC83CsFB152d8xzY8Y/edit?copiedFromTrash#gid=546488018) to a simplified sheet

The simplified formula in question is:

=FILTER(Data3!$B:$B,Data3!$C:$C=$B259,Data3!D:D)

Then, each formula, as it moves to be pasted to each column to the right, changes the last condition from Data3!D:D to Data3!E:E, Data3!F:F, and so on. I'm not sure how I would accomplish that with one formula.

Comment: @Aaron Is this imported in from Excel? Many of the formulas look Excel-built.

Comment: @Aaron I see the trouble.  I put a formula how I would do it in cell D403 on the MK.Help tab.  It doesn't bother with the INDIRECT() references.  It would expand if your data grew sideways.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! 
It worked great when I imported it into my actual sheet. All I had to do was edit the range of columns from D:O to D:EU since I have more there.

The issue I'm having now is super weird. I normally import this range using IMPORTRANGE back into my main sheet, but now suddenly it's only importing certain data... See below;  the imported data is missing the data from the middle column. How could this be possible?

[Data Page Data](https://imgur.com/39HPIeM)
[Imported Data](https://imgur.com/xABxT7A)

Comment: Ok, so.. Now, after a few minutes, the extra data showing in the "Data Page Data" linked above is now gone. It's almost as if it was not valid to begin with and the IMPORTRANGE knew that, but the original sheet did not. I had already tried refreshing the page, deleting/undoing the formula, etc. It just decided to finally catch up. Glitches are so maddening. I'll continue to monitor and hopefully it doesn't keep lagging & glitching. Thanks again for the help; this is a LOT less formulas now!

Comment: Sorry for the repeated follow-ups, but I need one more version of this formula. If you could take a look at the maroon section beginning with Row 818, those formulas have two conditions to the IF and I'm not sure how to spell that out the way you did it for the other formula.

Comment: @Aaron  if you have follow up questions you should make a new question - [How to ask follow up questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: @iansedano Thanks, that makes sense. Still new to this platform.

Answer (score 0):

I have filed an issue on the Issue Tracker to track this.

If you are affected by it go and "star" it to let Google know!

> ### https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190535938